# UIImage slow loading in a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIPageViewController` showing a `UIViewController` that contains a `UIImageView`.
The images displayed in the `UIImageView` originally come from the camera roll. I copy them in the application's folder. When I display the `UIPageViewController`, it loads the image for the current page and displays it:

```
if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath) {
  imageView.image = image
}
```

The problem is that it's really slow. Loading the first image is slow and then swiping is very slow.

I am testing this on my iPhone 5. I installed the app through XCode. Is there a way to make it faster? Should I save a smaller version of the image when I save the images from the camera roll into my application's folder?

Answer (score 1):

You could preload the images like Sergii suggested or load the images a background thread to avoid blocking the main thread.

```
    NSOperationQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
        if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath) {
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
                self.imageView.image = image
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load images you'll need before transitioning to UIPageViewController. Also, take a look at some projects for image caches
[FastImageCache](https://github.com/path/FastImageCache), [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), [Haneke](https://github.com/Haneke/Haneke)

Also, you can be interest in this article [Avoiding Image Decompression Sickness](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/10/avoiding-image-decompression-sickness/)

Answer (score 0):

To increase the speed of swiping you'd need to move where you are assigning the image to the UIImageView from the main thread to a background thread. 
There are a few ways to do this...

Using NSOperationQueue

```
 NSOperationQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
    if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath) {
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
            self.imageView.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can use GCD and calling `dispatch_async()`

```
if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        imageView.image = image   
    }
}
```

With regards to saving an image from the Camera Roll when/if you save it to your apps file system you could try using:

```
let qualityFloat = 1.0
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageFromCameraRoll, qualityFloat)
```

Playing around with qualityFloat (between 0.0 - 1.0) will change the file size of the image which could help you with the loading times.